# How to send data to aws kinesis firehose using kinesis agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-agent

I am trying to send below data to aws kinesis firehose using kinesis agent:
3985199||"ER1AA"|"2017"|"BMC PUBLIC HEALTH"|"17"||"2017-04-09-00.53.55.353280 -0400"|0|"1471-2458"|"13941J"|"C ,CC,D ,ES,JS,Q ,XC"|"A"|"N"|"APR 4  17"

I want to use 15 different custom fields to store these fields including null value and without double quotes.

Thanks in advance.